# custom keyboard dismissal button works great till focus shifts to another text field

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, keyboard-events

Here is my view showing the custom keyboard dismissal button.  See how beautiful it looks?  Works great too until you tap one of the other two text entry fields... then the dismissal button jumps back to where it was originally placed when I created it in the GUI designer.  Notice in the second screen shot after having tapped to the 2nd field, you can faintly see the location of the dismissal button completely hidden by the somewhat translucent keyboard.

Here, all is well with the world after the user has initially tapped any one of the 3 text entry fields...

[image]

and here is what it does when the user taps any one of the other 2 text fields...  The dismissal button jumps back downward in the interface and is hidden behind the keyboard...

[image]

Why would the button jump back to its xcode-designer-location as specified in the design tool? I can't understand what is making the button reset positions when the user taps a different field.

Here is the only code in play, at any time during execution.  I first capture the keyboard notification...

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    UIButton *but;
    but = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:4400];

    if ([but isHidden]) 
        [but setHidden:NO];

    // Get animation info from userInfo
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]    getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]          getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    // Animate up or down
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

    // get the custom dismissal button's frame so we can move it
    CGRect newFrame = but.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - keyboardEndFrame.size.height;
    but.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Can you log `keyboardEndFrame.size.height` to see if the value is what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, everything looks right when the keyboard is initially animated into position above the keyboard.  When I NSLog it I get: 2014-12-23 17:33:23.860 GW[92568:20251430] size of screen:480.000000 and size of keyboardframe:216.000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is orthogonal to your question, but the correct way to have a view that automatically appears above the keyboard is to set it as the `inputAccessoryView` of whatever text fields you require. That way you don't need to concern yourself with the keyboard frames.

I'm not sure what the problem in your specific case is but I think the willHide/willShow methods get called immediately after each other when you move from one text field to the next, and you're assuming an animation will be occurring.

You'll also hit problems with your current approach when the user hides or shows the autocomplete bar above their keyboard. Input accessory view is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, jrturton, I downloaded the PODs implementation of it and it is working swell...  One thing on that - I'm using it now as the accessory view for a UITextView but also need it to "sit on top of" the datepicker as well... Hoping it applies there also.

Comment: If you make a date picker the input view (as opposed to trying to animate that like a keyboard) then yes, it works.